# Groovy escaping question mark

Tags: rest, groovy, spock

I am using groovy to write spock tests.
I would like to get the url path with the `?` in it.
But it always turns into:

Sending request:

```
GET /test%3Fsearch=blub HTTP/1.1
```

I've tried to escape with `\\` or `\` or `/`

```
restClient.get(path: '/test?search='+search, requestContentType: 'application/json')
```

Comment: The issue is not the Groovy string escaping (that one doesn't just automatically URL-encode anything), but whatever you're using as a rest client.

Comment: Where do you get the `restClient` from?

Comment: @Peter import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
the idiomatic way worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using the RESTClient the more idiomatic way like:

```
restClient.get(path: '/test', query:[ search:'search' ], ... )
```